# BigCommerce Marketing Banner - Change Size

Tags: css, json, themes, bigcommerce

I have a pretty basic question, and couldn't seem to find anyone else with this issue. I want to reduce the height of the default Marketing Banner (BigCommerce). What code should I enter, and where? When I go to the Theme Editor (Chelsea Warm theme, Stencil/json), I can't find anything on the built-in BigCommerce banner. Looking forward to the advice, and I apologize if it's vague - I'm mainly a marketing/graphics person, just occasionally forced to work with code.

Best,
YT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default banner size should conform to the size of your banner content, but it looks like the Chelsea theme has some additional padding on the banner that's making it taller. You could enter this CSS into your footer scripts box (under Storefront>Footer Scripts in the control panel) to get rid of the padding:

```
<style>
    .banner.rte {
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>​
```

Comment: @ytayts Cool, glad that worked! Please feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you out :)